# Azure Functions broken after change to runtime?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I last published an Azure Function about a month ago. It has worked fine for weeks, but this afternoon I noticed it was failing. Inspection of the Test/Log blade showed an error - see below.

It seems that the runtime Azure.WebJobs.Extensions can't support the ExecutionContext type needed by my code. The current Azure runtime is 2.0.12050.0 (beta), but unfortunately I didn't record the version when I last published. Does anyone know if it has recently changed? Has anyone run into similar problems?

[image: screenshot].

Comment: They've pushed breaking changes (my apps broke friday morning). https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues for guidance (yeah its lame).

Comment: Microsoft support just pointed me to https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/129. Agreed, this isn't the way to support a product.

Comment: 2.0 is in preview, and breaking changes were announced in advance, so I think it's fair